# How to customise Material UI Tab's indicator width and positioning

Tags: tabs, material-ui, styling, indicator

I am using the *Material ui's tabs* and was able to make changes to the Tab's indicator. However, I am trying to reduce the width of the indicator to some fix width for each tab using styles. But it seems the indicator are positioned to left with some calculated value, and **giving it a width doesn’t center align the indicator**. Couldn't find appropriate solutions, kindly help me out. Here's the editable [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-indicator-centered-bfntu?file=/src/demo.js.).

Find below snippets:

1. Default fullwidth tabs. Indicator taking full width of the base button:
   [image: List item]
2. Width of indicator fixed, but not aligned to center below the tab label.
   [image: List item]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs), you need to attach a `span` element as the children of the indicator (using `TabIndicatorProps`). Then you could treat the indicator as a flex container, the `span` as a flex item with some fixed width.

Here's the component part:

```
<Tabs
  {...other}
  classes={{
    root: className,
    flexContainer: "flexContainer",
    indicator: "indicator"
  }}
  variant="fullWidth"
  TabIndicatorProps={{ children: <span /> }}
  centered
/>
```

Here's the styling part:

```
"& .indicator": {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  backgroundColor: "transparent",
  "& > span": {
    maxWidth: 40,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }
}
```

[Demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-indicator-centered-forked-ecpuy)

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add margin to the TabIndicatorProps like this:

```
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          TabIndicatorProps={{
            sx: {
              width: "20% !important",
              marginLeft: "15%",
            },
          }}
          centered
        >
```